# What to learn after JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've recently finished watching some beginner JavaScript tutorials; it's quite easy to understand. I'm trying to look for intermediate ones now, but I can't find any. So I've decided to not waste time while looking for some continuation on my JavaScript journey. What should I learn next? I prefer that which is important, and perhaps, closely related to JavaScript.

Comment: Try solving [some problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), that should be a test to see if you are ready to learn another language :).

Comment: After JavaScript? Trust me, [You don't know JavaScript](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS).

Comment: By the way, try out this quiz: http://perfectionkills.com/javascript-quiz/

Comment: learn jquery>angularjs>nodejs

Comment: one small way to test if you know or not check this out http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/

Comment: to learn jquery use this: https://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/

Comment: to be a webdeveloper you need to know js, jquery (angularjs, bootstrap, requires js), css3 ('less' too), html5 (audio, history, storage api), and either excel on graphic design or excel at php or .net

Comment: Thank you! I'm just studying in advance for my upcoming webdev class this upcoming school year in my country. Hehe.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer - You can be a successful web developer without jQuery, Angular, Bootstrap or RequireJS (there are other libraries/frameworks, and/or you can write your own), and without PHP or .net (there are other server-side languages/frameworks).

Comment: maybe...but you definitely won't be much sought after one. Just knowing javascript isn't going to take anyone very far. Most developers work in team, and it's not upto you to decide if to use any library or not.

Comment: I would respectfully disagree with @MuhammadUmer; JavaScript alone will take you very far. Browser plugins are written in JavaScript. Firefox OS apps are written in JavaScript. Chrome OS apps are written in JavaScript. You can even write Native Windows 8 applications in JavaScript. Server-side programming can be done with JavaScript. JavaScript is one of the most pervasive languages used today - master it, and you've got a sustainable career.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what your goal is, and what you have already learned.

If you want to become a *web developer*, you should learn some server-side web languages like PHP or ASP.NET.

If you want to become a general developer, it would be useful to know systems languages like Java or C++.

If you want to be a computer scientist, studying algorithms might be a good start.

Comment: I don't really have a final goal yet, I'm just learning in advance for this upcoming school year.

Comment: Then i'd say learn libraries like jquery, backbonejs, modenizr, and angularjs. Jquery has some important plugins that you should also get the hang of it.

Comment: I've heard about jquery, I think I'm gonna give that a try. Thanks!

Comment: great decision definitely try the links above..also to get real understanding you need to build things...try to think of things that would get you use whichever new thing you have learned.